# How to create foolproof user that is only allowed to video chat with one person

Tags: configuration, firewall, privileges, guest-account

I have to give a laptop to my 4 yr old who lives very far away from me, so that we can have regular video chats. I want to restrict any other use for that laptop, including video chats with other users. Specially, I am afraid she could play around with the keyboard and accept an incoming call from who-knows in the internet while her grandparents are fully unaware of what is happening.

Is there any way (using e.g. the ubuntu firewall) to restrict any video chat with anyone else other than me (I use google hangouts or skype or any other thing you may suggest).

Thanks.

Comment: You might try making the chat program private to a user only you know the password for on that laptop.  Then to make a call,  ssh into the laptop as that user and start an outgoing call back to yourself.   Might be tricky to tie it to the remote X11 screen.  But I suspect it's possible.  Maybe VNC is an option

Answer (score 0):

[Tox](https://tox.chat/faq.html) might be worth looking into. I haven't dug too deep into it, but I imagine you can pretty easily write a shell script that opens the client and calls you. It looks like you have to use a 76-character string to add "friends". There's a "NoSpam" string within there that you can change at-will, and people won't be able to add her if they somehow guess the 76-character ID.